# How to run Tensorflow object detection on iOS

Tags: ios, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to run object detection from a Tensorflow model (Inception or mobilenet) in an iOS app.

I have iOS Tensorflow image classification working in my own app and network following [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/ios)

and have Tensorflow image classification and object detection working in Android for my own app and network following [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo)

but the iOS example does not contain object detection, only image classification, so how to extend the iOS example code to support object detection, or is there a complete example for this in iOS? (preferably objective-C)

I did find [this](https://medium.com/@junjiwatanabe/how-to-build-real-time-object-recognition-ios-app-ca85c193865a) and [this](https://github.com/csharpseattle/tensorflowiOS), but it recompiles Tensorflow from source, which seems complex,

also found [Tensorflow lite](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/ios),

but again no object detection.

I also found an option of converting Tensorflow model to Apple Core ML, using Core ML, but this seems very complex, and could not find a complete example for object detection in Core ML

Answer (score 1):

You need to train your own ML model. 
 For iOS it will be easier to just use Core ML. Also tensorflow models can be exported in Core ML format. You can play with this sample and try different models. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/recognizing_objects_in_live_capture

Or here:
https://github.com/ytakzk/CoreML-samples

Comment: does exporting tensorflow object detection models to Core ML work? From what I read, it seems like this does not work very well.

Comment: is there a Core ML example app that shows a camera view with object detection boxes overlay, like the Tensorflow Android TFDetect app?

Comment: Yes, here is the sample video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q73ZcqV6pPc
And here is the code: https://github.com/vonholst/SSDMobileNet_CoreML

Comment: I've used tensorflow lite models in the past and they worked just well.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up following this demo project,

https://github.com/csharpseattle/tensorflowiOS

It provided a working demo app/project, and was easy to switch its Tensorflow pb file for my own trained network file.

The instructions in the readme are pretty straight forward.
You do need to checkout and recompile Tensorflow, which takes several hours and 10gb of space. I did have the thread issue, used the gsed instructions, which worked. You also need to install Homebrew.

I have not looked at Core ML yet, but from what I have read converting from Tensorflow to Core ML is complicated, and you may loose parts of your model.

It ran quite fast on iPhone, even using an Inception model instead of Mobilenet.